# "due to follow" -> is this grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

> [image]
>
> When I was young, I was unwillingly brought along due to follow my parents' dreams.

I was taught **due to** has two meanings. When you use it as 'because of', **nouns** or **gerunds** should follow. On the other hand, you put it with Be-verb to talk about things that are expected in a way of 'be due **to verb**'. But I never saw this kind of **due to** (pic related). Could someone explain it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not grammatical.

Keeping **due to**, it could be rewritten to something like one of the following—using a noun as you indicated:

> When I was young, I was unwillingly brought along due to **my parents** following their dreams.
>   When I was young, I was unwillingly brought along due to **my parents** wanting to follow their dreams.

---

But there is no requirement to use the *-ing* form of a verb after *due to* either (so long as there is an intervening noun).

For instance, these sentences would also work:

> When I was young, I was unwillingly brought along due to my parents **who** followed their dreams.
>   When I was young, I was unwillingly brought along due to my parents **who** wanted to follow their dreams.

---

However, all of those versions are a little bit awkward. Better versions of the sentence would replace *due to* with *by*:

> When I was young, I was unwillingly brought along **by** my parents **who** followed their dreams.
>   When I was young, I was unwillingly brought along **by** my parents **who** wanted to follow their dreams.